# Exclude onclick() event from div

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I have this code:

```
<body onclick="myFunction();">
<head>
<!-- some javascript here -->
<body>
<div id="element1">
   <div id="element2">
      <div id="element3">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now I want to prevent the `onClick` on `<body>` triggering if the user clicks inside the `<div id="element3">` area.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the area by hijacking the click handler and calling `event.stopPropogation();` (`window.event.cancelBubble = true;` in older versions of ie)

```
<div id="element1" onclick="event.stopPropagation(); window.event.cancelBubble = true;">sadsadsadsad
       <div id="element2">                
         <div id="element3"> 
             </div>        
         </div>     
     </div>  
 </body>
```